# Как принять json в laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Как мне принять форму в laravel, отправленную через vue.js?
Сейчас при отправке формы, мне выдает ошибку `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

```
    public function createApplication(Request $request){
        dd($request);
        $json = $request->all;
        $data = json_decode($json, true);

        Application::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'message' => $data['message'], 
        ]);
    }
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/createApplication', [App\Http\Controllers\IndexController::class, 'createApplication']);
```

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input v-model="form.name" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя *">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input v-model="form.phone" type="text" placeholder="Введите телефон*">
    </div>
    <div class="form-block">
        <textarea v-model="form.message"  cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Сообщите вопрос"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-button">

        <button v-if="active" v-on:click="submit">Отправить заявку</button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    data: () => ({
        active: true,
        form: {
            name: null,
            phone: null,
            message: null
        }
    }),

    methods: {
        submit() {
            let data = JSON.stringify(this.form);
            axios.post("api/createApplication", data )
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.active = false;
                    console.log(this.active);
                    console.log(this.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function createApplication(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();
    
    Application::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'message' => $data['message'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: все равно выдает ошибку `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`. В логах ошибка `local.ERROR: Undefined array key "name" {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined array key \"name\" at`